# How to interleave two arrays into a new array

Tags: java, arrays, list, append, interleave

- Creates a new List that holds the elements of list1 interleaved
- with the elements of list2. For example, if list1 holds
- <"over","river","through","woods"> and list2 holds <"the","and","the">,
- then the new list should hold
- <"over","the","river","and","through","the","woods">. Alternating between
- list1 and list2. If one list is longer, the new list will contain all of
- the extra values from the longer list at the end. For example, if list1
- holds <"over","river","through","woods"> and list2 holds <"the","and">
- then the new list should hold
- <"over","the","river","and","through","woods">.

I suck at programing and can't see the logic on the last part of this assignment. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.
//*

```
private static List<String> mergeLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    long max = Math.max(((File) list1).length(),((File) list2).length());
    ArrayList<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (i < list1) {
            newlist.append(list1[i]);
            {
        if (i < list2) {
            newlist.append(list2[i]);
        }
    }


            return newlist; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can't get this code to work. I need it to create a new array list and interleave the elements from two different array lists.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MadPhysicist Dang ill try to post it better or just hop to redit. How do I delete this question?

Comment: If suggest editing the question. I suspect that with a properly worded question you'll get good help here.

Comment: If you want to delete instead of editing, that's an option too, but remember that the purpose of questions is to help future readers more than just you. Both buttons appear immediately below the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point I will leave it for now, I just got a good answer to it. I will fix the format when I have time tonight. Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I'll try to post better questions in the future.

Comment: No worries. Ping me when you make the edit. I'll remove all my negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely had the right idea, you almost got it. Guess you don't suck at programming that much :). You can use properties of a `List` for this, without casting to a `File`.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("over");
        list1.add("river");
        list1.add("through");
        list1.add("woods");

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("the");
        list2.add("and");

        mergeLists(list1, list2);
    }

    private static List<String> mergeLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {

        // Get the max length of both arrays
        int max = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());

        // Initialize new list
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        // add an element of the first list to the new list (if there are more elements)
        // and then add an element from the second list to the new list (if there are more elements)
        // and repeat...
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (i < list1.size()) {
                newList.add(list1.get(i));
            }

            if (i < list2.size()) {
                newList.add(list2.get(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newList);
        return newList;
    }
```

Comment: Thats perfect! thank you for your help and your time.